# Is an extension of compact Hausdorff topological groups compact?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $1 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{a} B \xrightarrow{c} C \rightarrow 1$ be a short exact sequence of topological groups (i.e., all maps are continuous, $A = \mathrm{Ker}(c)$, and $C = \mathrm{Coker}(a)$). Suppose that $A$ and $C$ are compact Hausdorff. Does it follow that $B$ is compact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assume that $a$ is a homeomorphism onto its image.  Indeed, if you don't then you get counterexamples with $C=1$: let $A$ be a finite group with the discrete topology and let $B$ be the same group with the indiscrete topology.  You also have to assume that $c$ is a topological quotient map.  Indeed, if you don't then you get counterexamples with $A=1$: let $B$ be the circle with the discrete topology and $C$ be the circle with the usual compact Hausdorff topology.

With these extra topological assumptions, everything works out fine.  First note that $a(A) = \ker c$ is *closed* in $B$ since $C$ is Hausdorff, so the identity point of $B$ is closed as we can check it in the Hausdorff $A$ (using that $a$ is a homeomorphism onto a closed image).  Hence, $B$ is Hausdorff (as for any topological group with closed identity point).  This didn't use the compactness (and is also not at all interesting).

Now that $B$ is Hausdorff, we can argue with nets: if $\{x_i\}$ is a net in $B$ then we can pass to a subnet so that $\{c(x_i)\}$ converges to some $y \in C$.  Writing $y = c(x)$ and replacing $x_i$ with $x_i x^{-1}$ then reduces us to the case that $c(x_i) \rightarrow 1$ in $C$.  But $C$ has the quotient topology from $B$ by hypothesis, so after passing to a subnet we can choose $a_i \in A$ such that $x_i a_i^{-1} \rightarrow 1$ in $B$.  Since $A$ is compact Hausdorff, passing to a further subnet allows us to arrange that $a_i \rightarrow a$ in $A$, so $x_i a^{-1} \rightarrow 1$ in $B$; i.e., $x_i \rightarrow a$ in $B$.

QED

You may like to consider the more interesting/useful case when "compact" is relaxed to "locally compact".

Comment: One might mention that regular monomorphisms in the category $Top$ are subspace embeddings, and regular epimorphisms in $Top$ are topological quotients, so under the categorically correct meaning of short exact sequence in the category of topological groups, one gets these desired hypotheses.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate the step where passage to a subnet allows a choice of $a_i \in A$ with $x_i a_i^{-1} \rightarrow 1$, i.e., how to choose such a subnet?

Comment: @QuestionMark: Consider the poset of open neighborhoods of 1 in $B$. For each such $U$, $UA$ is open; hence, $c(U) = UA/A$ is open in $C$ and by definition of the quotient topology this gives the poset of open neighborhoods of 1 in $C$ except with possibly massive redundancies. Anyway, for each $U$ we can find $i(U)$ so that $c(x_i)\in c(U)$ for all $i\ge i(U)$. Let $J$ be the poset of pairs $(U,i)$ with $i \ge i(U)$. The natural map $J\rightarrow I$ is cofinal, and for each $j=(i,U)\in J$ we define $x_j=x_i$ and can pick $a_j \in A$ so that $x_j a_j^{-1}\in U$. Now rename $J$ as $I$.

Comment: Thanks. I did not recall previously that the definition of a subnet allows an indexing set that need not be a subset of the original indexing set, which caused my troubles at this step.

Comment: By the way, I think your $C = 1$ counterexample doesn't work because every finite topological space is compact.

Comment: @QuestionMark: Oh, I assumed you wanted $B$ to be compact Hausdorff (not just compact).  Anyway, I think we both agree that you meant to assume $A$ has the subspace and $C$ the quotient topology (so they're actually categorical kernels and cokernels).

Comment: @ToddTrimble:  Even better, if we work within the more limited category of topological groups then the subspace topology on kernels and quotient topology on quotient by normal subgroup are categorical too.

Comment: In case anybody is interested in this: for the locally compact case alluded to at the end of the answer one may consult Thm. 5.25 of Hewitt, Ross "Abstract harmonic analysis I".